# Facebook Credits. Error 1151

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

I'm developing an application on Facebook, and I need to have the possibility to integrate my application on other sites (with connections to Facebook by the Facebook JavaScript API).

On Facebook, I can buy some things on an application using Facebook Credits, but on some other site, when I call the Facebook purchase dialog, I get this error:

```
API Error Code: 1151
API Error Description: Sorry, but this app may not be eligible to accept Facebook Credits.  
If this app has accepted credits before, please try again.
Error Message: Invalid Application
```

Or is there a Facebook purchase dialog we can use only on Facebook?

Answer (score 11):

This happens because the payment interface can only be called from an iframe application running on Facebook.

Comment: Anyone know if it is still the case in Dec 2013 that FB credits cannot be used on external sites, not canvas apps on the facebook.com domain? All answers to questions like these on SO are several years old.